# Function signatures as type

Tags: go

I have a type for a function signature defined as

```
type MessageListener func(msg *Message) bool
```

In a struct, I have the following function defined which basically registers a Listener with the function signature defined by the type above

```
func (wm *WM) AddListener(listener *MessageListener) error {
...
}
```

My service struct

```
type Service struct {
     ...
}

func (service *Service) receiveMessage(msg *Message) bool {
    ...
}
```

Why am I getting an incompatible type error when I do

```
wm.AddListener(&service.receiveMessage)
```

Doesn't `service.receiveMessage` have the type `MessageListener` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function is a reference you do not need to use any pointers or try to take an address of the function.
Just declare

```
func (wm *WM) AddListener(listener MessageListener) error {
...
}
// and get rid of taken address of function
wm.AddListener(service.receiveMessage)
```

Answer (score 1):

`MessageListener` is already a *function pointer* so you can simply define `AddListener` as

```
func (wm *WM) AddListener(listener MessageListener) error {
    //...
}
```

A listener then can be registered by calling `wm.AddListener(service.receiveMessage)`.

From specifications of [Address operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators):

> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a pointer of type *T to x. The operand must be addressable, that is, either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the addressability requirement, x may also be a (possibly parenthesized) composite literal. If the evaluation of x would cause a run-time panic, then the evaluation of &x does too.

So you can't takes the address of a function/method. However, you can takes the address of a variable that stores function/method. It is valid to declare the listener as

```
func (wm *WM) AddListener(listener *MessageListener) error {
    //...
}
```

but then when registering a listener, do the following:

```
var fn MessageListener = service.receiveMessage
wm.AddListener(&fn)
```

and when calling the listener:

```
msg := Message{//...}
(*wm.listener)(&msg)
```

which adds unnecessary codes for converting function variable to pointer then converting back to function variable.